# css apply styling to all elements except those in the last row

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

[image]

I have a product category page with 3 products per row. I want every row to have a border bottom **except** for the last row. This should have no border bottom. The last row may contain 1, 2, or 3 `<li>` elements.

The current code that I'm using applies the border-bottom property to every 3rd `<li>` element, which is not quite what I want.

CSS:

```
.products li {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.products li:nth-child(3n){
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1) solid;
}

.products li:nth-child(2-PREVIOUS-SIBLING-ELEMENTS){
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1) solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="products">
   <li>Product</li>
   <li>Product</li>
   <li>Product</li>
   <li>Product</li>
   <li>Product</li>
   <li>Product</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I figured this out. The second ruleset below accounts for any amount of products on the last row.

```
.products li:nth-child(3n){
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1) solid;
}

.products li:nth-last-child(-n + 3):nth-child(3n + 1),
.products li:nth-last-child(-n + 3):nth-child(3n + 1) ~ li {
    border: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6rso3t85/

A better fiddle, adjusting the display as asked, and showing the three use cases

http://jsfiddle.net/6rso3t85/1/

Comment: Your ruleset is ok, but the fiddle wasn't displaying the three columns of the OP question. I have also added the three cases, just to show it better

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick: (Tested on FF 33)

```
.products li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/br9w647u/1/)

[This](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/) is a great website for testing **nth-child** stuff.

**EDIT:**

Your situation is quite tricky and I think it's not possible only using CSS.

I made a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mesefovuxe/2/watch), which uses JavaScript to achieve your desired result.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="products">
 <li>Product</li>
 <li>Product</li>
 <li>Product</li>
 <li>Product</li>
 <li>Product</li> 
 <li>Product</li>
 <li>Product</li>
 <li>Product</li>
 <li>Product</li>
 <!-- more products -->
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.products li {
    width: 30.33333%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

**JS**

```
var size = $('.products li').size();

var previous = Math.floor((size)/3)*3;
if (size % 3 === 0 ) {
  previous = size - 3;
}

for (var i = previous; i < size; i++ ) {

    $('.products li:eq(' + i + ')').css( 'border-bottom' , 'none');
}
```

Comment: This solution is only valid if there is 1 <li> on the last row.

If there are 2 or 3 <li> elements on the last row, your solution will simply remove the "border-bottom" from the final <li> element as opposed to the final 2 or 3 <li> elements

Comment: Does the new code meet your requirements? Perhaps you have to use nth-last-child(-n+4)

Comment: No. Because we don't know how many items there are going to be on the last row. There could be 1, 2, or 3

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand exactly how the result should look like. Could you add an image or something to your question, which shows your desired result. This would help me a lot. nth-last-child(-n+2) is wrong too?

Comment: Please see the attached image

Comment: try to add additional <li> elements. It should work too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63640/discussion-between-pbaldauf-and-adam-scott).